# Typescript - Understanding export/import

Tags: typescript

I am learning Typescript. I've read articles about namespacing and `import`/`export`.

In my own project, I created some classes. Since it is my first project, I forgot to put the `export` keyword on some of them, but I noticed that they are still accessible in other files without needing to import them. I also noticed that a class with import need to be export/import to be used somewhere else.

Why can I do that? Is it ok to do this? When is using `export` mandatory, and when is it not?

I thought I should always `export`/`import` my classes and modules, but the code is working without them.

```
class CoordinateModel {
    public x: number;
    public y: number;
    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

And in another file, I can use it

```
import * as d3 from "d3";

module Mouse {
    export function getMousePosition(container:d3.ContainerElement): CoordinateModel {
        var m = d3.mouse(container);
        return new CoordinateModel(m[0], m[1]);
    }

    export function showMousePositionInElement(elementClassName: string, container: d3.ContainerElement) {
        var m = Mouse.getMousePosition(container);
        d3.select("." + elementClassName).html(m.x + ", " + m.y);
    }
}

export = Mouse;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file has no top level `import` or `export` statements then its in global scope, meaning all top level items are visible everywhere without the need to `import` anything.

That's basically the old JavaScript way of doing things before ES6 modules came into existence. The old TypeScript `module` (now called `namespace`) syntax was a way to avoid name collisions in global scope. The new JavaScript (and TypeScript) way of writing modules is to use `import` and `export` syntax.

So yes, these days you *should* `export class CoordinateModel`, in which case other files will need to `import` it from the file rather than rely on it being in global scope. In most cases you do not need the `namespace` (what you wrote as `module Mouse`, which could also be written as `namespace Mouse` with the latest syntax, meant to disambiguate with ES6 modules). You can read more about [Namespaces and Modules in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, a file in TypeScript is a module ONLY if you export something from it. Once you do that, only the things exported from that file are accessible, and you must import them.

That's what you're doing in the other file (I'll call it `module.ts` as I don't know the name), exporting `Mouse`. If you add another `ts` file to your project and do

```
let a = getMousePosition(null);
```

you'll get an error because `getMousePosition` is not defined. In this case you'll need to do, at the beginning of the file:

```
import { getMousePosition } from "./module";
```

Of course, defining a module inside `module.ts` means not much in your case, as you're exporting it. You could have easily defined a namespace. You export the contents of `Mouse`, not `Mouse` itself.

if you remove your `export = Mouse` line, then you'd need to do, in the other file:

```
let a = Mouse.getMousePosition(...);
```

And you wouldn't need an import.